# DocuSign API return URL that transfers control back from WebView to React-Native app after redirection

Tags: android, ios, react-native, docusignapi

I am using React-Native to build an Android application. I am also using the DocuSign Java API.

My workflow submits a RecipientViewRequest and receives a URL that the android app must view within a WebView to perform the signing:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/core_recipes/CoreRecipes.java

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

This is the code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  WebView,
  Component,
} = React;

class DocuSignView extends Component {

  render() {
    var recipientViewURL = this.props.route.data.url;
    console.log('Recipient URL is: ' + recipientViewURL);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: recipientViewURL, method: 'GET'}}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
        >
      </WebView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The DocuSign servers redirect the WebView to a `returnURL` that I provide.

How can I specify a returnURL that will return control back to my React-Native android application?

(A generic answer for React-Native either iOS or Android would be even better).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the onNavigationStateChange event handler to intercept and seize control from the WebView:

```
render() {
    var recipientViewURL = this.props.route.data.url;
    console.log('Recipient URL is: ' + recipientViewURL);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: recipientViewURL, method: 'GET'}}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.whenNavigationStateChanges.bind(this)}
        >
      </WebView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  whenNavigationStateChanges(navState){
    var navigator = this.props.navigator;
    var parsed = Url.parse(navState.url, true);
    if (parsed.hostname == 'YOUR_HOSTNAME'){
      console.log("Event is: " + parsed.query.event);
      navigator.pop();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure **Custom URL Schemes**.

For Android: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

For iOS: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html